# Issue Sorting Arrays With New Xcode Beta 4 In Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have been using Xcode 6 Beta 2 and I have an array of a custom class (Show()) with misc String variables. I want to sort by a particular class string (Show Name) and I had it working fine like this:

```
currentShowsArray = sort(currentShowsArray){$0.showName < $1.showName}
```

Now this no longer works and I get an error that says '()' is not convertible to '[(Show)]'

I can't seem to be able to find the new syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the beta 4 release notes:

> The global `sort` function now mutates its first argument, and a new
>   `sorted` function always returns a new collection.

So either

```
currentShowsArray = sorted(currentShowsArray){$0.showName < $1.showName}
```

or, if the array is mutable,

```
sort(&currentShowsArray){$0.showName < $1.showName}
```

Comment: If I use the sort method on Array, that seems to have less repetition than using the global sort function. If I use the global sort, it shows 16 iterations while using sort method on the array uses 9 iterations only. Is it because of this mutating features ?